# Asignar un valor a un dropdownlist de una busqueda

Tags: asp.net

```
Estoy usan el Visual Studio 2015 y SQL server 2019
En mi formulario tengo los siguientes controles
```

<asp:TextBox ID="txtCpostal" runat="server" placeholder="Código postal" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnBuscascp" runat="server" Height="34px" ImageUrl="~/prueba/img/btn-busca-cliente.png" OnClick="imgbtnBuscascp_Click" Width="37px" />

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDel" runat="server" placeholder="Delegación o Municipio" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocal" runat="server" placeholder="Localidad" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEst" runat="server" placeholder="Estado" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColonias" runat="server" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:DropDownList>

Tengo el siguiente método el cual va y busca el código postal a una tabla de mi base de datos:
    public bool buscaCodigospostales(string cpostal, ref string municipio, ref string localidad, ref string colonia, ref string estado)
    {
           using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString()))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            string sql = @"SELECT Cat_Codigopostal, Cat_Municipio, Cat_Localidad, Cat_Colonia, Cat_descEstado 
                           FROM catalogo.codigospostales
                           INNER JOIN catalogo.estados ON catalogo.codigospostales.Cat_cveEstado = catalogo.estados.Cat_cveEstado
                           WHERE Cat_Codigopostal =  @cpostal";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpostal", cpostal);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read()) {
                municipio = Convert.ToString(reader["Cat_Municipio"]);
                localidad = Convert.ToString(reader["Cat_Localidad"]);
                colonia = Convert.ToString(reader["Cat_Colonia"]);
                estado = Convert.ToString(reader["Cat_descEstado"]);
            }
            conexion.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }

En mi formulario tengo un botón el cual al hacer click va y hace la búsqueda de los códigos postales y dependiendo el código que se llamó a buscar el resultado lo muestra y lo asigna en algunos controles de tipo textbox

    protected void imgbtnBuscascp_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string cpostal = txtCpostal.Text;
        string delegacion = txtDel.Text;
        string localidad = txtLocal.Text;
        string colonia = ddlColonias.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string estado = txtEst.Text;

        if (objConsultaClientes.buscaCodigospostales(cpostal, ref delegacion, ref localidad, ref colonia, ref estado))
        {
            txtDel.Text = delegacion;
            txtLocal.Text = localidad;
            ddlColonias.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(colonia);
            txtEst.Text = estado;

        }
    }
```

El resultado de la busqueda se llenan correctamente mis controles textbox, pero el dropdownlist no se llena
¿Cómo le asigno el valor de la colonia a mi dropdownlist?

Comment: Hola, espero te encuentres bien. A la hora que cargas el DropDownList ¿utilizas como valor para el value "Cat_Colonia"?, de no ser así con SelectedValue no vas a poder seleccionar el campo como tal, sería bueno que nos puedas compartir el código con el que cargas tu DropDownList para confirmarlo. Espero mi comentario te sea de ayuda.

Comment: clsConexion objCnx = new clsConexion();


string sSQL2 = @"SELECT Cat_cvePostal, Cat_Colonia FROM catalogo.codigospostales";
            objCnx.LlenaDDLSql("conn", sSQL2, "Cat_cvePostal", "Cat_Colonia", ref ddlColonias, "S");

Comment: Veo que envías los parámetros a un método que desarrollaste, pero aún no me queda claro, cual de los 2 campos estás usando para llenar el text y cual el value en el DropDownList, podrías indicarme el orden de los parámetros que recibes en este método? Ejemplo:  objCnx.LlenaDDLSql( connexión, sqlQuery, value, text, component, param )

Comment: * Parametros: sCadenaConexión  Nombre en el web.config de la cadena de conexión con el que se conecta la base.
        *              sSQL                Sentencia SQL.
        *              sCampoCve           Campo Clave del dropdownlist.
        *              sCampoDes           Campo Descripción del dropdownlist.
        *              ddlControl          Control donde se van a guardar los datos.
        *              sOpcionVacia        Opción para determinar si el control llevara al principio una opción vacia (S/N).
        * 
        */